# Is there any way to install and unpack a github repository through code without using git bash and the like?

Tags: python, c#, c++, git

Currently I have a problem where I need to install all contents of a github repository (https://github.com/reversinglabs/reversinglabs-yara-rules) through code without using git bash or the like.
In this case I need to fully install the yara repository from said github.
Any one knows a way to do it in c,c++,c#,python?

Unfortunately till now I have yet to succeed in any way.

Comment: You might consider working with one of the implementations for the language of libgit2.

Comment: Did you really spend 3-5 years learning each one of these four languages, each, in order to have average level of experience and knowledge in order to understand the complete implementation of the git wire protocol, in either one of these languages?

Comment: No I have not, in fact I am a noobie and want to learn. I have around 2 years in all those languages and I made myself a project that where I am stuck on a small part of it which requires me to get some yara files from a known repository through runtime.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what the problem with writing a bash script (or even powershell on a windows system) is ?

Comment: git is meant to be used by a human, not by a program (e.g. if you have a conflict, how would the program resolve it ?) Anyway, if you really want to use git commands programmatically, you will need to use libgit2. In your case, since you only want to download a repository, you may not need it (maybe a simple curl request would do the job)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what part of bash, etc, you do not want to use. A simple way otherwise is to just call git through `std::system()`

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    std::system("git clone ...");
}
```

I have used it in many cases where I need to integrate git commands in a c++ program.

Comment: Dont you have to do this through git bash though? How would that work?

Comment: What operating system are you using? There is only "git bash" on Windows. If you have your paths setup right, your program would find git anyway. And you would need to start your program somehow anyway right? How do you do that without using bash? And if so, why dont you just want to use a bash script?

Comment: I am using windows 10, my program cant seem to find git unfortunately.

Comment: Have you installed git? And have you set up the path variables correcly? https://linuxhint.com/add-git-to-path-windows/

Answer (score 1):

GitHub offers a zip download of all the code it hosts.
Use whatever language and library you like to do the equivalent of:

```
curl -o yara-rules.zip https://github.com/reversinglabs/reversinglabs-yara-rules/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip 
unzip yara-rules.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

only if you are on linux you can use:

```
#Python 
import os 
url = input("Url: ")
os.system("git clone " + url)
```

or in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string inputUrl;
   cin >> inputUrl;
   inputUrl = "git clone " + inputUrl;
   system (inputUrl.c_str()); //You need to convert it with .c_str()
}
```

Hope that this can be useful!